# Design pattern for class compatibility

Tags: c++

I would like to know which would be the **most efficient** (regarding speed) way to solve the following problem:

Let's say we have a class `AFoo`, having a simple header file as:

AFoo.h

```
class AFoo {
public:
    double x;
    //Additional methods/variables belonging only to AFoo
};
```

Now, I receive a set of classes that **I do not define** (i.e. some other stubborn programmer is creating those classes), which all "share" the `x` variable. We could imagine that one member of such set is the class `BFoo`, which looks like:

BFoo.h

```
class BFoo {
public:
    double x;
    //Additional methods/variables belonging only to BFoo
};
```

Now, I have a function somewhere which accepts some pointer to an `AFoo`

```
void doSomething(AFoo *pnt){
    //does operations with the x member only.
}
```

I would really like that my `doSomething` function accepts also a pointer to a `BFoo` or any class of the set I was given. The abstraction of `x` into a new class `Foo` is no solution because the stubborn programmer refuses to inherit from it. I thought of using template functions, but the inconvenient is that I would have to recompile every time the stubborn programmer creates a new class.

My first try was to define an interface which behaves the following way:

```
class AlternativeFoo {
public:
    virtual double & getX() = 0;
};
```

so I can define another class like

```
class AlternativeAFoo: public AlternativeFoo{
public:
    double & getX(){ return mPoint.x; };
private:
    APoint mPoint;
};
```

Now I can change my `doSomething` method to accept a pointer to an `AlternativeFoo` variable, which works fine. However, this solution is noticeably slower than template classes. Is there a design pattern that I am missing which does not compromise performance? Thank you very much!

EDIT:
As a concrete example of the problem, imagine I code a library which I want to be compatible with several definitions of the same abstract idea, for example, a 2D point which has coordinates x and y. This definitions can come from APIs in video game design software or whatever, and they all share the fact that they have `x` and `y` coordinates as member variables of the same type. How can I make a piece of code compatible with all of them?

Comment: I think `doSomething` should accept a `double&` directly.

Comment: Your solution to create an interface, imho, is contradictory with this statement: _The abstraction of x into a new class Foo is no solution because the stubborn programmer refuses to inherit from it._ The stubborn programmer will need to inherint from your interface

Comment: @appleapple What if instead of x, the class has some behavior shared among all classes? For example, all the classes have the `[ ]` operator overloaded to return some double (like a vector), behavior I would like to take advantage of inside `doSomething`? I think in a more complex case, it would be hard to pass a lot of variables.

Comment: @Amadeus it is not, because it is me writing the interfaces, i.e. I would write an implementation of the interface for each class the stubborn programmer gives me.

Comment: @Malanche If a class has some behaviours that are shared among all class, it should be factoried out, and them, this new class used as argument of your `dosomething` function. BTW, are you willing to write an interface for every class that your stubborn programmers write?

Comment: @Malanche then you should use template or interface. BTW, you would not need to recompile for every new class (if you put template definition in header).

Comment: @Amadeus but is there a way I can factor this out without altering the definitions of the set of classes? My main problem is that I am not in control of the classes I want to use, I only have a guarantee that the behavior will not change.

Comment: @Malanche Maybe [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) or a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: I think the price to pay in performance for the convenience of the interfaces is what I have to pay. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would go with template. but I don't get your point with *"but the inconvenient is that I would have to recompile every time the stubborn programmer creates a new class."*

Comment: @Jarod42 Wouldn't I have to add something like `template class doSomething<ZFoo>(ZFoo *pnt);` (with ZFoo the name of the new class) and recompile? I thought templates are instructions that are not built until an explicit instance appears.

Comment: You need to recompile either way - you're _introducing a new type_, and presumably some code _using_ the new type, so how are you ever _not_ going to recompile? You also have to recompile if you manually write a facade for each new class, as you suggested.

Comment: and there is no reason why the interface version should be slow (even assuming you can make it work with the constraints you have)

Answer (score 1):

You just want a template that operates on `pnt->x` (or whatever).

I.e.

```
template <typename AnyFoo>
void doSomething(AnyFoo * pnt)
{
    pnt->x = 10;
}
```

Your compiler will give you an error message if you try to `doSomething("Something not a Foo e.g. a const char *")`